# How do I get the data from ADB and output it to a CMD variable?

Tags: android, windows, variables, cmd, adb

Please can you attempt to fix my stupid code?
I want to do this:

`adb shell pidof [android_pkg]>>ISAPPON`, but that won't work because it still thinks it's an ADB command.

```
C:\Users\[BLANK]>adb shell pidof [android_pkg]>>ISAPPON

C:\Users\[BLANK]> echo %ISAPPON%
%ISAPPON%
```

I tried the above, but to no avail.
I expected it to set the %ISAPPON% value to [APP PID], but it just stayed and left a default value.

-Trisiegt

Answer (score 0):

You can use (for Windows)

```bash
for /f %G in ('adb shell pidof [android_pkg]') do set "ISAPPON=%G"
```

for Linux and Mac

```bash
ISAPPON=$(adb shell pidof [android_pkg])
```